# how can use remainder operator to get remaining KB when converting into MB?

Tags: java

```java
public class MegaByteConverter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printMegaBytesAndKiloBytes(2500);
    }

    public static void printMegaBytesAndKiloBytes(int kiloByte) {
        if (kiloByte < 0) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Value");
        }
        System.out.println(kiloByte + " KB =" +
                kiloByte / 1024 + " MB AND " + (kiloByte / 1024) % kiloByte + " KB");
    }
}
```

I'm not able to get remaining KBs. there's something wrong with `(kiloByte/1024) % kiloByte`.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no need to perform `(kiloByte/1024)` prior to the `%` operation.  That is the cause of your problem.

What you have:

```
int kiloByte = 2500;
int megaByte = (kiloBytes / 1024); // 2500 / 1024 == 2
int remainder = megaByte % 1024;   // 2 % 1024 == 2 which is not what you want
```

compared to:

```
int kiloByte = 2500;
int megaByte = (kiloBytes / 1024); // == 2 (MB)
int remainder = kiloBytes % 1024;  // == 452 (KB) which is your desired outcome
```